Multi-reader study design: split-plot or fully crossed?
I am a radiologist designing a study where 230 CT scans of cancer patients will be evaluated by 5 radiologists. There will be two sets of evaluations: one where radiologist is aided by an AI Computer-aided detection (CAD) tool, and one where they are unaided. Each radiologist will score lesions on a scale from 1-5, and time spent per case-review will be recorded. I will allow 4 weeks gap before the same radiologist interprets their cases again to allow them to forget their previous readings.
The final measurements across the two diagnostic methods (radiologist alone versus radiologist plus CAD) will be compared in terms of diagnostic accuracy and time-spent in reading scans.
I am reading this paper https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3522484/ and  its authors report a split-plot study design in a similar CAD study. In their study, however, once a radiologist finished reading a case without CAD, they immediately turn CAD on, and report any additional findings. So there is a slight difference. I have unlinked the paired interpretations.
Other papers in radiology have used fully-crossed study designs https://repository.ubn.ru.nl/handle/2066/237631. A split-plot design seems very efficient but I am wondering if there are any gotcha's unknown to me in following this route. I would love to hear practising  statisticians opinions on both designs.

Just to be clear each radiologist is reading each 230 scans, twice.  Once with CAD and once without.  This seems like a very powerful experiment, especially if the radiologist are randomized on whether they use CAD first or second and the order of the scans are random.  A split plot allows collecting information with limit resources (i.e. one plot of land).  If resources are not limited, then it is better to perform a full randomized experiment as initially proposed.

Yes, your idea of the experiment is correct. Thank you
